# How do I include a batch file into an Eclipse Java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file

I have a Java application that worked fine when I ran it via command line (I coded it using Notepad++ ). However, when I tried to port  the same Java application  into Eclipse it's not working for me. It's an application featuring a batch file that is supposed to restart a program that was interrupted midway:

the batch file :

```
set CLASSPATH=./bin 
java fixedMessageApp.FixedMessageSequenceServer 4446 mylogfile.txt 0 0 
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul 
rem java fixedMessageApp.FixedMessageSequenceClient localhost 4444 myclientLog.txt 0
```

The Java file :

```
public class FixedMessageRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) { 
            System.out.println("usage: java FixedMessageRunner CMD"  ); 
            System.exit(0);
        } 
        try {
            //for (;;) {            
                String current = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath();
                System.out.println("Current dir:"+current);
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args[0]); 
                pb.directory(new File(current));          //("C://FixedMessageApplication//"));
                Process p = pb.start();
                p.waitFor();
            //}
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this work in Eclipse, like it does in CMD ?  In Eclipse, when this is run it will just hang :

[image]

Comment: is the "current dir" value as expected? Have you tried doing a "debug"?

Comment: It might be because you are calling p.waitFor(); https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor() and it could be causing the thread to wait until the process is finished

Comment: I would also add, try adding a system.out.println("Hello"); after the p.waitfor(); and run in the command line. My guess is that the command line has the same issue as eclipse, you just didn't release it.

Comment: You could catch the outputstream of the process and look at it. In some cases, calling windows batch files as executables does not work.